# c tcp socket non blocking receive timeout

Tags: c++, c, sockets

Trying to write a client which will try to receive data till 3 seconds. I have implemented the connect method using select by below code.

```
//socket creation 
m_hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

m_stAddress.sin_family           = AF_INET;
  m_stAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(pchIP);
m_stAddress.sin_port             = htons(iPort);

m_stTimeout.tv_sec = SOCK_TIMEOUT_SECONDS;
m_stTimeout.tv_usec = 0;

//connecting to server
long iMode = 1;
int iResult = ioctlsocket(m_hSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);

connect(m_hSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&m_stAddress, sizeof(m_stAddress));

long iMode = 0;
iResult = ioctlsocket(m_hSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);

fd_set stWrite;
FD_ZERO(&stWrite);
FD_SET(m_hSocket, &stWrite);

iResult = select(0, NULL, &stWrite, NULL, &m_stTimeout);            

if((iResult > 0) && (FD_ISSET(m_hSocket, &stWrite)))
  return true;
```

But I cannot figure out what I am missing at receiving timeout with below code? It doesn't wait if the server connection got disconnected. It just returns instantly from select method. 
Also how can I write a non blocking socket call with timeout for socket send.

```
long iMode = 1;
int iResult = ioctlsocket(m_hSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);

fd_set stRead;
FD_ZERO(&stRead);
FD_SET(m_hSocket, &stRead);

int iRet = select(0, &stRead, NULL, NULL, &m_stTimeout);

if ((iRet > 0) && (FD_ISSET(m_hSocket, &stRead)))
{
  while ((iBuffLen-1) > 0)
  {
    int iRcvLen = recv(m_hSocket, pchBuff, iBuffLen-1, 0);
    if (iRcvLen == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else if (iRcvLen == 0)
    {
      break;
    }

    pchBuff  += iRcvLen;
    iBuffLen -= iRcvLen;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have not presented the code by which you create the socket, so I don't know what kind it is.  Inasmuch as you seem to think that there is a meaningful sense in which it can be "disconnected", however, it must be some type of stream socket.  In that case, why should your program continue to try to read from it after a disconnection?  No data will ever be forthcoming until the socket is reconnected, and that doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: I think I am exiting the receive loop once I get a SOCKET_ERROR and thats the wrong. As for a single read it might return SOCKET_ERROR and evetually for next reads it might report a success, so I guess here I need to check for time elapsed. Is it so?

Comment: Use write and error sets: select(<MAXSOCK+1>, <read-set>, <write-set>, <error-set>, timeout);

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to select should not be 0.
Correct usage of select can be found here :
http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=2933

the first parameter should be the max value of your socket +1 and take interrupted system calls into account if it is non blocking:

```
/* Call select() */
do {
   FD_ZERO(&readset);
   FD_SET(socket_fd, &readset);
   result = select(socket_fd + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
} while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
```

This is just example code you probably need the timeout parameter as well.
If you can get EINTR this will complicate your required logic, because if you get EINTR you have to do the same call again, but with the remaining time to wait for.

Comment: Here I'm dealing with a single socket instance. So shall I really need to consider that (socket_fd + 1)? Moreover I cannot loop like this, I need to check whether my receive method has failed to received data for maximum timeout limit.

Comment: I am not saying you have to take this code as is. But you should check your return codes, and see if it has EINTR if so you need to take it into account, and yes you need socketdescriptor +1

Comment: if EINTR is in the picture you have to create a time variable and take the elapsed time into account. Can complicate the code a bit.

Comment: I think I am exiting the receive loop once I get a SOCKET_ERROR and thats the wrong. As for a single read it might return SOCKET_ERROR and evetually for next reads it might report a success, so I guess here I need to check for time elapsed. Is it so? If that be the case I need not to use the select() to wait for a timout. Only need to set the socket into non blocking mode. Am I correct?

Comment: blocking is easier, you cannot get EINTR if it is blocking mode.

Comment: Yes, blocking is easier. In blocking mode I can simply set a timeout with setsockopt().

Answer (score 0):

I think for non blocking mode one needs to check the recv() failure along with a timeout value. That mean first select() will return whether the socket is ready to receive data or not. If yes it will go forward else it will sleep until timeout elapses on the select() method call line. But if the receive fails due to some uncertain situations while inside read loop there we need to manually check for socket error and maximum timeout value. If the socket error continues and timeout elapses we need to break it.

I'm done with my receive timeout logic with non blocking mode. 
Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
  bool bReturn = true;
  SetNonBlockingMode(true);

  //check whether the socket is ready to receive
  fd_set stRead;
  FD_ZERO(&stRead);
  FD_SET(m_hSocket, &stRead);
  int iRet = select(0, &stRead, NULL, NULL, &m_stTimeout);

  DWORD dwStartTime = GetTickCount();
  DWORD dwCurrentTime = 0;

  //if socket is not ready this line will be hit after 3 sec timeout and go to the end
  //if it is ready control will go inside the read loop and reads data until data ends or
  //socket error is getting triggered continuously for more than 3 secs.
  if ((iRet > 0) && (FD_ISSET(m_hSocket, &stRead)))
  {
    while ((iBuffLen-1) > 0)
    {
      int iRcvLen = recv(m_hSocket, pchBuff, iBuffLen-1, 0);
      dwCurrentTime = GetTickCount();

      if ((iRcvLen == SOCKET_ERROR) && ((dwCurrentTime - dwStartTime) >= SOCK_TIMEOUT_SECONDS * 1000))
      {
        bReturn = false;
        break;
      }
      else if (iRcvLen == 0)
      {
        break;
      }

      pchBuff  += iRcvLen;
      iBuffLen -= iRcvLen;
    }
  }

  SetNonBlockingMode(false);
  return bReturn;
```

Comment: Anyone with review comments?